# How to convert this code from iOS swift to Android Kotlin

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, kotlin

I'm trying to convert this Swift code to Kotlin Android and having problems.

```
Swift code:

public let kCORNER_RADIUS_BUTTON: CGFloat = 4.0
```

I have converted the CGFloat java class that i found below

```
/**
 * CGFloat

 * @author [Harald Kuhr](mailto:harald.kuhr@gmail.com)
 * *
 * @author duncan
 */
class CGFloat : Number {

    private val value: Double

    constructor() {
        value = 0.0
    }

    constructor(d: Double) {
        value = d
    }

    override fun toByte(): Byte {
        return value.toByte()
    }

    override fun toChar(): Char {
        return value.toChar()
    }

    override fun toDouble(): Double {
        return value
    }

    override fun toFloat(): Float {
        return value.toFloat()
    }

    override fun toInt(): Int {
        return value.toInt()
    }

    override fun toLong(): Long {
        return value.toLong()
    }

    override fun toShort(): Short {
        return value.toShort()
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        // From Double.hashCode
        val bits = java.lang.Double.doubleToLongBits(value)
        return (bits xor bits.ushr(32)).toInt()
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        // Modified Double.equals
        return other is CGFloat && java.lang.Double.doubleToLongBits(other.value) == java.lang.Double.doubleToLongBits(value)
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return value.toString()
    }

    companion object {
        // Inspired by JNA NativeLong and IntegerType
        val SIZE = Integer.MAX_VALUE
    }

}
```

In Kotlin code I do this

```
public val kCORNER_RADIUS_BUTTON: CGFloat = 4.0
```

but getting error message "the floating-point literal does not conform to the expected type CGFloat"

Comment: Why not just use a `Double`? Also, you can't assign a literal to a type like that. You'd have to do `CGFloat(4.0d)`.

Comment: I can't.  I have to follow the Swift code to the exact.

tried 

    public val kCORNER_RADIUS_BUTTON: CGFloat(4.0d)

now getting "property getter and setter expected" error

Comment: That seems to be a fairly restrictive and unnecessary requirement when porting between OSes. Your `CGFloat` class is just mimicing `Double`, so why not type alias it? `typealias CGFloat = Double`. Then you can refer to it as `CGFloat` (if you must) and use `Double` directly without having to maintain a useless wrapper.

Comment: Thanks. I will try typealias.  I'm not a Swift developer so this is all new to me.

Last question: How would I set the typealias to use it globally in the kotlin project?

Comment: You may want to check out this comparison: http://nilhcem.com/swift-is-like-kotlin/

Answer (score 2):

If you must use `CGFloat` as you have it written, you'll have to construct one directly. You can't just assign a primitive type to it, Kotlin has no facility to understand that.

```
 val kCORNER_RADIUS_BUTTON: CGFloat = CGFloat(4.0)
```

However, because your `CGFloat` class doesn't do anything that `Double` doesn't already does, I would recommend using that instead. It seems that you have requirements (that I would push back on) to port this exactly, ignoring the conventions of the language you are porting to. In that case, I would just typealias Double to CGFloat.

```
typelias CGFloat = Double
```

Then you can use it anywhere you want:

```
fun doSomething(foo: CGFloat): CGFloat { ... }
```

Comment: The use of typealias is the "correct" solution to your problem. If you are porting things over and using primitives as defined objects that are nothing special like that then this is your solve. If however you need to have additional capabilities, then extend the Number like how you are and override the operator functions to support interaction with primitives as well.